# JavaScript is not refilling the label

Tags: javascript, html

In this code I'm trying to add the label if the user check the Radio box and remove the text if the user uncheck the label but it is not working. [the HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Iga.png)

[image]

```
function billingFunction()
{
    if (document.getElementById('same').value==true)
        {
        var name = document.getElementById('shippingName').innerHTML;
        var zip=document.getElementById('shippingZip').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('billingName').innerHTML=name;
        document.getElementById('billingZip').innerHTML= zip;
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('billingName').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('billingZip').innerHTML= "";
        }

}
```

Comment: Hello Obaid. I believe the issue is you need to use the `value` property of the input fields rather than `innerHTML`

`name = document.getElementById('shippingName').value; document.getElementById('bllingName').value = name`;

Comment: please add the real part of this HTML, not a picture of it

Answer (score 0):

## If you want to change label, try this code.

```js
function billingFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked) {
    var name = document.getElementById('shippingName').innerHTML;
    var zip = document.getElementById('shippingZip').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('billingName').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('billingZip').innerHTML = zip;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billingName').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('billingZip').innerHTML = "";
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <label id="shippingName">Name</label>
  <input />
</div>

<div>
  <label id="shippingZip">ZIP</label>
  <input />
</div>

<div>
  <input id="same" type="checkbox" onchange="billingFunction()" />
  <label for="same">Same?</label>
</div>

<div>
  <label id="billingName"></label>
  <input />
</div>

<div>
  <label id="billingZip"></label>
  <input />
</div>
```

## If you want to set input value on checkbox checked try this code

```js
function billingFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked) {
    var name = document.getElementById('shippingName').value;
    var zip = document.getElementById('shippingZip').value;
    document.getElementById('billingName').value = name;
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = zip;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billingName').value = "";
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = "";
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked) {
    var name = document.getElementById('shippingName').value;
    var zip = document.getElementById('shippingZip').value;

    document.getElementById('billingName').value = name;
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = zip;
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="shippingName">Name</label>
  <input id="shippingName" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="shippingZip">ZIP</label>
  <input id="shippingZip" />
</div>

<div>
  <input id="same" type="checkbox" onchange="billingFunction()" />
  <label for="same">Same?</label>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="billingName">Name</label>
  <input id="billingName" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="billingZip">ZIP</label>
  <input id="billingZip" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use the input'names with the form ID, and oninput event

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ;
myForm.same.oninput=()=>
  {
  myForm.billingName.value = (myForm.same.checked) ?  myForm.shippingName.value : ''
  myForm.billingZip.value  = (myForm.same.checked) ?  myForm.shippingZip.value  : ''
  }
```

```css
label { display: block; margin: .7em; }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
    <label>Name: <input type="text" name="shippingName"></label>
    <label>Zip Code: <input type="text" name="shippingZip"></label>
  </fieldset>

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="same"> Is the Billing Information the Same ? </label>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>
    <label>Name: <input type="text" name="billingName"></label>
    <label>Zip Code: <input type="text" name="billingZip"></label>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```